# How to use Query function to list products in stock?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, unique, spreadsheet

In my query function (cell H3), I want to list products which are acutally in stock.

If Salesperson Amy's note says "Sold" then this product would be considerd as Sold. (Even if Salesperson jack says "Reserved")

And I also want to remove all duplicates.  Thank you so much for your help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ax1MdRFnxisMYJqfoLWsP6Cm75bC51Ga2QvGjdAemnU/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY({B2:D, C2:C&D2:D}, "select Col1 where Col4 contains 'Sold'")))
```

### update:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, NOT(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY({B2:D, C2:C&D2:D}, 
 "select Col1 where Col4 contains 'Sold'"))))))))
```